# Managed C# method for adding a Printer

Tags: c#, printing

Is there a managed C# way to add a printer to Windows? I've found [a reference](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/224587-addprinter-using-c) to using

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv",CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr AddPrinter(string myserver, 
   uint dwLevel, ref PRINTER_INFO_2 pi );
```

But I'd rather avoid linking into the native library. Is this my only option for adding a printer in .NET 2.0?

Comment: You want to use "Native" method or "native" (read, in built library) method? Because it seems like you want managed code but native! :-S

Comment: I want managed, but all I found was an unmanaged function.